# How exactly do probability distributions help modeling/making decisions?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, statistics

I am an elementary/wanna-be statistician/data scientist from South Korea. I have been studying a variety of theories of mathematical statistics and different probability distributions. (I apologize for bad English if there is one!)

I am wondering how exactly these distributions help a curious data scientist derive any inference or make decisions when modeling.

For example, if a variable of a dataset is estimated to follow Poisson distribution with a specific value of parameter lambda. What can it actually tell you? What kind of inference can I learn? What can it imply when I am looking into a couple of specific data points or areas?

Comment: Great question, posted it on quora also in case answer is not received in stackexchange community https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-exactly-probability-distributions-help-a-data-scientist-in-modelling-decision-making-or-how-can-a-data-scientist-derive-any-inference-or-make-decisions-when-modeling-some-day-to-day-business-examples-would-be